# getting JSONArray with retrofit 2 on android

Tags: android, json, retrofit2

```
//get user and password form JSONArray
public void loginapi(){
    String username = user.getText().toString();
    String password = passwd.getText().toString();

    ApiInterface apiService = ApiClient.getClient().create(ApiInterface.class);

    Call<List<Akses>> call = apiService.getEmployeeAkses(donat, username, password);
    call.enqueue(new Callback<List<Akses>>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<List<Akses>> call, Response<List<Akses>> response) {
            String waduser,wadpass;
            ArrayList<Akses> aksesList = new ArrayList<Akses>();
            waduser = aksesList.get(0).getUsername().toString();
            wadpass = aksesList.get(0).getPassword().toString();
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<List<Akses>> call, Throwable t) {
            Log.e("Errore : ", t.getMessage());
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Terjadi Kesalahan masalah API", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        }
    });

}
```

How to get JSONArray with the code ?

> waduser = aksesList.get(0).getUsername().toString();
>   wadpass = aksesList.get(0).getPassword().toString();

when the above code is logged, it does not produce anything.
what should i do ?

Comment: what is your json response?

Comment: You are never using using your server response. You are creating a new local array and trying to get user name and password from it which would result in null.

Comment: thank you for your response.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try this

```
  public void loginapi(){
    String username = user.getText().toString();
    String password = passwd.getText().toString();

    ApiInterface apiService = ApiClient.getClient().create(ApiInterface.class);

    Call<List<Akses>> call = apiService.getEmployeeAkses(donat, username, password);
    call.enqueue(new Callback<List<Akses>>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<List<Akses>> call, Response<List<Akses>> response) {
            String waduser,wadpass;

            // you should use (ArrayList<Akses>) response.body; 

            ArrayList<Akses> aksesList = (ArrayList<Akses>) response.body;


            waduser = aksesList.get(0).getUsername().toString();
            wadpass = aksesList.get(0).getPassword().toString();
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<List<Akses>> call, Throwable t) {
            Log.e("Errore : ", t.getMessage());
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Terjadi Kesalahan masalah API", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        }
    });

}
```